# Issues with android blur using Renderscript

Tags: android, renderscript, android-renderscript

I am using following code for building blurred background for my imageview.

```
public class BlurBuilder {
    private static final float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.2f;
    private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 25f;

    public static Bitmap blur(Context context, Bitmap image) {
        int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
        int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

        Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
        Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
        theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
        theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
        theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
        tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

        return outputBitmap;
    }
}
```

Blur is built fine for most times, but get bad over time, eventually my app crashes without any crash log. Upon running on emulator, I have seen the following error after severe testing:

```
09-01 15:05:03.230 4624-9758/? E/RenderScript: rsAssert failed: ret == bytes || mShutdown, in frameworks/rs/rsFifoSocket.cpp at 83
09-01 15:05:03.238 4624-9781/? E/RenderScript: rsAssert failed: ret == bytes || mShutdown, in frameworks/rs/rsFifoSocket.cpp at 83
09-01 15:05:03.242 4624-10128/? E/RenderScript: rsAssert failed: ret == bytes || mShutdown, in frameworks/rs/rsFifoSocket.cpp at 83
09-01 15:05:03.242 4624-9610/? E/RenderScript: rsAssert failed: ret == bytes || mShutdown, in frameworks/rs/rsFifoSocket.cpp at 83
09-01 15:05:03.242 4624-9781/? E/RenderScript: rsAssert failed: ret == bytes || mShutdown, in frameworks/rs/rsFifoSocket.cpp at 83
09-01 15:05:03.250 4624-9767/? E/RenderScript: rsAssert failed: ret == bytes || mShutdown, in frameworks/rs/rsFifoSocket.cpp at 83
09-01 15:05:03.254 4624-9758/? E/RenderScript: rsAssert failed: ret == bytes || mShutdown, in frameworks/rs/rsFifoSocket.cpp at 83
... (same error - many more times and then crash)
```

I have following queries in this regard:

1. I am using following gradle config for renderscript:

   compileSdkVersion 23
   buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

   defaultConfig {
           applicationId "package "
           minSdkVersion 19
           targetSdkVersion 23
           multiDexEnabled true
           **renderscriptTargetApi 19
           renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true**
   }

What is the recommended version of renderscript library ? 
Should I import dependencies from `android.support.v8.renderscript.Allocation or`android.renderscript` package ?

2. Can I achieve the blur effect without using renderscript library ?

Comment: what is the build-tools version you are using?

Comment: buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

Comment: One more question, what is the device and Android version you tested your app? I would suggest you try two things though: 1. try to cache "rs" and "theIntrinsic" after you created it. 2. also try to use the latest Build-Tools (24.0.1)

Comment: Device - MK Plug PC 809IV, Intel plug pc and some emulators. All use android version 4.4.4. Can you please explain more on how the caching would help ?

Comment: Given the tests devices are mostly X86 devices, I guess this is a bug for the X86 RenderScript support lib. The caching may not solve the problem but it can potentially help the performance, because RenderScript.create() and IntrinsicBlur.create() are quite heavy.

Comment: @MiaoWang - That was valuable information, thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending more than a day, I figured out the following:

1. App is crashing because there is an exception being thrown by Renderscript library. This usually happens often in devices with low processing power. This exception is not a Java exception, cannot be caught.
2. Use the following code for another way to issue blur (without using renderscript library):

   ```
   public static Bitmap fastblur(Bitmap sentBitmap) {

   int radius = (int) BLUR_RADIUS;

   int width = Math.round(sentBitmap.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
   int height = Math.round(sentBitmap.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);
   sentBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sentBitmap, width, height, false);

   Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);

   if (radius < 1) {
       return (null);
   }

   int w = bitmap.getWidth();
   int h = bitmap.getHeight();

   int[] pix = new int[w * h];
   Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
   bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

   int wm = w - 1;
   int hm = h - 1;
   int wh = w * h;
   int div = radius + radius + 1;

   int r[] = new int[wh];
   int g[] = new int[wh];
   int b[] = new int[wh];
   int rsum, gsum, bsum, x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw;
   int vmin[] = new int[Math.max(w, h)];

   int divsum = (div + 1) >> 1;
   divsum *= divsum;
   int dv[] = new int[256 * divsum];
   for (i = 0; i < 256 * divsum; i++) {
       dv[i] = (i / divsum);
   }

   yw = yi = 0;

   int[][] stack = new int[div][3];
   int stackpointer;
   int stackstart;
   int[] sir;
   int rbs;
   int r1 = radius + 1;
   int routsum, goutsum, boutsum;
   int rinsum, ginsum, binsum;

   for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
       rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
       for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
           p = pix[yi + Math.min(wm, Math.max(i, 0))];
           sir = stack[i + radius];
           sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
           sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
           sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
           rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);
           rsum += sir[0] * rbs;
           gsum += sir[1] * rbs;
           bsum += sir[2] * rbs;
           if (i > 0) {
               rinsum += sir[0];
               ginsum += sir[1];
               binsum += sir[2];
           } else {
               routsum += sir[0];
               goutsum += sir[1];
               boutsum += sir[2];
           }
       }
       stackpointer = radius;

       for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {

           r[yi] = dv[rsum];
           g[yi] = dv[gsum];
           b[yi] = dv[bsum];

           rsum -= routsum;
           gsum -= goutsum;
           bsum -= boutsum;

           stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
           sir = stack[stackstart % div];

           routsum -= sir[0];
           goutsum -= sir[1];
           boutsum -= sir[2];

           if (y == 0) {
               vmin[x] = Math.min(x + radius + 1, wm);
           }
           p = pix[yw + vmin[x]];

           sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
           sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
           sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);

           rinsum += sir[0];
           ginsum += sir[1];
           binsum += sir[2];

           rsum += rinsum;
           gsum += ginsum;
           bsum += binsum;

           stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
           sir = stack[(stackpointer) % div];

           routsum += sir[0];
           goutsum += sir[1];
           boutsum += sir[2];

           rinsum -= sir[0];
           ginsum -= sir[1];
           binsum -= sir[2];

           yi++;
       }
       yw += w;
   }
   for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
       rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
       yp = -radius * w;
       for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
           yi = Math.max(0, yp) + x;

           sir = stack[i + radius];

           sir[0] = r[yi];
           sir[1] = g[yi];
           sir[2] = b[yi];

           rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);

           rsum += r[yi] * rbs;
           gsum += g[yi] * rbs;
           bsum += b[yi] * rbs;

           if (i > 0) {
               rinsum += sir[0];
               ginsum += sir[1];
               binsum += sir[2];
           } else {
               routsum += sir[0];
               goutsum += sir[1];
               boutsum += sir[2];
           }

           if (i < hm) {
               yp += w;
           }
       }
       yi = x;
       stackpointer = radius;
       for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
           // Preserve alpha channel: ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] )
           pix[yi] = ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] ) | ( dv[rsum] << 16 ) | ( dv[gsum] << 8 ) | dv[bsum];

           rsum -= routsum;
           gsum -= goutsum;
           bsum -= boutsum;

           stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
           sir = stack[stackstart % div];

           routsum -= sir[0];
           goutsum -= sir[1];
           boutsum -= sir[2];

           if (x == 0) {
               vmin[y] = Math.min(y + r1, hm) * w;
           }
           p = x + vmin[y];

           sir[0] = r[p];
           sir[1] = g[p];
           sir[2] = b[p];

           rinsum += sir[0];
           ginsum += sir[1];
           binsum += sir[2];

           rsum += rinsum;
           gsum += ginsum;
           bsum += binsum;

           stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
           sir = stack[stackpointer];

           routsum += sir[0];
           goutsum += sir[1];
           boutsum += sir[2];

           rinsum -= sir[0];
           ginsum -= sir[1];
           binsum -= sir[2];

           yi += w;
       }
   }

   Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
   bitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

   return (bitmap);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, man!! I was stuck in this error for more than a day. This code snippet helped.